# How can I change the 'internal' URL prefix (Chromium Source)?

Tags: browser, chromium

I'm currently working on a Chromium fork and I'm wondering if there's a good way to change the "Internal URL Prefix" (e.g. chrome://). Does anyone know where you can change it (or rather, if there's a file similar to the `chromium_strings.grd` where you can change stuff like that.
Pretty new to StackOverflow so excuse any newbie mistakes please!

Comment: You will have to make lots of changes. I would recommend searching for `chrome://` in your `src` folder then then replacing it and keep trying to compile

Comment: That's a bit of a 'band aid' solution in my opinion - there's a LOT of occurrences and automatically replacing each one would break lots of things while manually doing it would take ages. @Asesh

Comment: There's no standard way to do it and Chromium is a very big and rapidly changing project. So that's the only option you have

Comment: Do you know which files specifically are used to **register** the custom schemes? (So I can test it without changing the pages linking to the custom url first)